# How to dynamically crop image based on it's parent height

Tags: html, css, image

```
    .imageButton {
       width: 14px;
       height: 50px;
    }
    .divClass{
       width:100px;
       height: 30px;  
    }

<div class="divClass"><img class="imageButton" /></div>
```

here the height of the .divClass is dynamic.Now my problem is while displaying in need to crop this image according to the div's height. for example:- if div's height is 30 then img needs to be cropped `top-((img's height-div's height)/2)` and `bottom-((img's height-div's height)/2)`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

apply 100% height and width to image

```
.imageButton {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

you can adjust height and width according to your need. you can specify it 50% if you want it to be half of parents height or width

hope it'll help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible in your case setting image as div's background instead of placing it in HTML would have the desired effect

```
.divClass {
    background: transparent url('imageButton.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```